# Как удалить оценку студенту (SQL)

Tags: sql, база-данных

Я написала запрос чтобы удалили оценку студенту, но он выдает ошибку

```
DELETE FROM grade WHERE grade_id, subject_id, student_id('5','21', '190111')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какую ошибку то выводит?

Comment: У оператора `where` другой синтаксис. В вашем случае будет ... `where grade_id = 5`...

Comment: SQL syntax синтаксеческая ошибка

Comment: DELETE FROM grade WHERE grade_id = '5', subject_id = '11', student_id = '190111' Вот так?

Comment: @NastyaPavlova если идёт сравнение со строковыми полями, то да, так, если эти поля числовые, то без кавычек

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELETE FROM grade WHERE grade_id = 5 AND subject_id = 21 AND student_id = 190111`

Comment: Извините можете подсказать как удалить все оценки одному студенту

Comment: DELETE FROM grade WHERE student_id = 190111